# Change Shape Of Titlebar Buttons

Tags: titlebar, button

Is there any way that I can change the shape of these buttons to be square? It is Ubuntu's last LTS version with Gnome, previously these buttons were square but now I can't change it back.

The buttons, preview.

[image: The buttons, preview]

Comment: try some gtk3 themes

Answer (score 0):

The look and shape of the buttons on the title bar is determined by the GTK theme that you are using. Themes can be changed in Gnome Tweaks, Appearance tab. That utility is not installed by default. The default theme in Ubuntu is Yaru. The list of themes available depends on the themes that are installed on your system. Some additional themes can be installed using synaptic package manager or the terminal. Third party themes are available at sites like [Gnome Look](https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/).

You can only change themes at once. Unfortunately, in Gnome, which Ubuntu uses in its default desktop, there is no user exposed granular control to change individual aspects of the desktop appearance. Any such changes would require to manually edit or changing icon files or edit style code.

Comment: I see, so I have to find a GTK theme which has square buttons. Thank you!